# Using Georeferencer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am using QGIS 3.22 Stable version.

I'm trying to georeference two dat. files with *Georeferencer* plugin in the 'Raster' section of QGIS. I manually choose all the points using "*tsunami_before*" as base raster and the correspective points on "*tsunami_after*". I have chosen in the transformation setting the *Thin Plate Spline* as transformation type and the *Nearest Neighbour* as resambling method. When I start the georeferencing, the modified raster appears on my QGIS main screen, but on the georeferencer it doesn't show me the errors associated with every points (it gives me all zeros).

What is the possible reason for which the errors are null?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is because of this:

> I have chosen in the transformation setting the Thin Plate Spline

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThinPlateSpline.html

> Given a set of data points, a weighted combination of thin plate
> splines centered about each data point gives the interpolation
> function that passes through the points exactly while minimizing the
> so-called "bending energy."

Residuals cannot be used for evaluating the quality of TPS transformation because warped pixels always fit exactly with the ground control points. The other areas of the image may have however large distortions.

Change the transformation type to for example Polynomial 2 and you will see non-zero residuals.

Answer (score 0):

Using a different transformation setting it actually works, but my professor used Thin Plate Spline and the errors came out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).